# Replace Id with name

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

## What I have

I have some data in json format like this:

```
var data = [{id: 1, name="AB", designation=1},
            {id: 2, name="CD", boss= 1, designation=2},
            {id: 3, name="EF", boss= 1, designation=2},
            {id: 4, name="GH", boss= 1, designation=2},
            {id: 5, name="IJ", boss= 2, designation=3},
            {id: 6, name="KL", boss= 3, designation=3},
            {id: 7, name="MN", boss= 3, designation=3},
            {id: 8, name="OP", boss= 7, designation=4},
            {id: 9, name="QR", boss= 3, designation=3},
            {id: 10, name="ST", boss= 1, designation=2}];

var designations = [{id: 1, name: "Principle"},
                    {id: 2, name: "HOD"},
                    {id: 3, name: "Teacher"},
                    {id: 4, name: "Student"}];
```

In the above data notice that boss field is referencing to the same array while designation is referencing to a different array.

## What I want

I want to show this data in a table:

```
id | name | boss | designation
---+------+------+------------
 1 | AB   | SUP  | Principle
 2 | CD   | AB   | HOD
 3 | EF   | AB   | HOD
 4 | GH   | AB   | HOD
 5 | IJ   | CD   | Teacher
 6 | KL   | EF   | Teacher
 7 | MN   | EF   | Teacher
 8 | OP   | MN   | Student
 9 | QR   | EF   | Teacher
10 | ST   | AB   | HOD
```

## What am I planning

Right now I am showing the above mentioned table using javascript. Now I am planning to learn and implement same example using Angular.js. Is there anything in-built for angularjs to do such things? If not then please tell me how do I do that using javascript?

Comment: This data isn't valid JSON. Can you check this and update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `data.map(...)` to make a projection with the format you need to show in the table.

For instance you could do something like:

```
$scope.tableContent = data.map(function(d) { return new {
   id: d.id, 
   name: d.name, 
   boss: data.filter(function(x) {return x.id == d.boss; })[0],
   designation: designations.filter(function(des) { des.id == d.designation; })[0];
});
```

Or something like that. Then you simply bind tableContent to an ng-repeat and render the HTML like you desire with angular.

Something like this:

```
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat='row on tableContent'>
       <td>{{row.id}}</td>
       <td>{{row.name}}</td>
       <td>{{row.boss.name}}</td>
       <td>{{row.designation.name}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: add the ng-repeat example ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the short and easy answer. I got it to work after some experiments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.grep` function:

```
$scope.getDesignation = function (Id) {
        return jQuery.grep(designations, function (a) {
            return a.Id == Id;
        })[0].name;
    }
```

And call `getDesignation` function from html.

Example:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>boss</th>
            <th>designation</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
            <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.boss }}</td>
            <td>{{ getDesignation(item.designation) }} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: OP is asking for an angularJs solution, i don't think jQuery was on his mind.

Comment: @Schuere, this is solution for question. What are you saying? I don't understand

Comment: We should be encouraging the use of native Javascript/Angular solutions. Personally I think using lodash map would be much cleaner.

Comment: @vaqifrv, this was before you added the angularJS part ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{id: 1, name: "AB", designation: 1},
            {id: 2, name: "CD", boss:  1, designation: 2},
            {id: 3, name: "EF", boss:  1, designation: 2},
            {id: 4, name: "GH", boss:  1, designation: 2},
            {id: 5, name: "IJ", boss:  2, designation: 3},
            {id: 6, name: "KL", boss:  3, designation: 3},
            {id: 7, name: "MN", boss:  3, designation: 3},
            {id: 8, name: "OP", boss:  7, designation: 4},
            {id: 9, name: "QR", boss:  3, designation: 3},
            {id: 10, name: "ST", boss:  1, designation: 2}];

var designations = [{id: 1, name: "Principle"},
                    {id: 2, name: "HOD"},
                    {id: 3, name: "Teacher"},
                    {id: 4, name: "Student"}];
             


for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var boss = data[i].boss;
        var b  = eval(i+1);
            var bossId = data[i].boss-1;
            if(boss){

          var bossName = data[bossId].name;
            }
         var name  = data[i].name;
         var designationId = data[i].designation;
         var designationName = designations[designationId-1].name;


        if(!boss){
            $("#test tbody").append("<tr><td>"+(b)+"</td><td>"+name+"</td><td>SUP</td><td>"+designationName+"</td></tr>");
       
        } else {
         $("#test tbody").append("<tr><td>"+(b)+"</td><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+bossName+"</td><td>"+designationName+"</td></tr>");
        }

       }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="test">
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>id</th>
  <th>name</th>
  <th>boss</th>
  <th>designation</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**VIEW**

```
<html ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
    <div ng-repeat="item in data">
      {{item.name}}
      <br/> Designation : {{getDesignationById(item.designation).name}}
      <br/>
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>

</html>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])



// controller
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.data = [{
    'id': 1,
    'name': "AB",
    'designation': 1
  }, {
    'id': 2,
    'name': "AC",
    'designation': 2
  }, {
    'id': 3,
    'name': "ER",
    'designation': 3
  }, {
    'id': 4,
    'name': "TG",
    'designation': 4
  }]

  var designations = [{
    'id': 1,
    'name': "Principle"
  }, {
    'id': 2,
    'name': "HOD"
  }, {
    'id': 3,
    'name': "Teacher"
  }, {
    'id': 4,
    'name': "Student"
  }];

  $scope.getDesignationById = function(id) {
    return $filter('filter')(designations, { id: id })[0];
  }

}]);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/q2Lyz59n/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var dataMap = data.reduce((p, c) => {p[c.id] = c.name; return p;}, {});
var designationsMap = designations.reduce((p, c) => {p[c.id] = c.name; return p;}, {});

data.forEach((v) => {
    if(v.boss && dataMap[v.boss]){
        v.boss = dataMap[v.boss];
    }
    if(v.designation && designationsMap[v.designation]){
        v.designation = designationsMap[v.designation];
    }
});

var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("mainController", mainController);
function mainController($scope){
    $scope.data = data;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>boss</th>
    <th>designation</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in data track by $index">
    <td>{{item.id}}</td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.boss}}</td>
    <td>{{item.designation}}</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/t50Lpgb2/)

Answer (score 0):

**plain JS (no jQuery needed)**

First change the data array to contain the transfered values.

then fill table rows

```
var data = [{id: 1, name:"AB", boss= 0, designation:1},
            {id: 2, name:"CD", boss: 1, designation:2},
            {id: 3, name:"EF", boss: 1, designation:2},
            {id: 4, name:"GH", boss: 1, designation:2},
            {id: 5, name:"IJ", boss: 2, designation:3},
            {id: 6, name:"KL", boss: 3, designation:3},
            {id: 7, name:"MN", boss: 3, designation:3},
            {id: 8, name:"OP", boss: 7, designation:4},
            {id: 9, name:"QR", boss: 3, designation:3},
            {id: 10, name:"ST", boss: 1, designation:2}];

var designations = [{id: 1, name: "Principle"},
                    {id: 2, name: "HOD"},
                    {id: 3, name: "Teacher"},
                    {id: 4, name: "Student"}];

for(var key in data){
    for(var id in designations){
    if(designations[id].id == data[key].designation){
        data[key].designation = designations[id].name;
      break;
    }
  }

    for(var id in data){
    if(data[id].id == data[key].boss){
        data[key].boss = data[id].name;
      break;
    }
  }
}

var table = new Array();
var row = new Array();
for(var key in data[0]){
    row.push(key);
}
table.push(row);

for(var index in data){
    row = new Array();
  for(var column in data[index]){
        row.push(data[index][column]);
  }
  table.push(row);
}
```